# Given that $J$ is a matrix in Jordan Normal Form, What is the Jordan normal form associated to $J^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

This seems pretty straight forward, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

I have that If $A \in M_n$ and $B \in GL_n$, then

$J = B A B^{-1}$, so 
$J^T = (BAB^{-1})^T$.

So this give us that $J^T = B^T A^T (B^T)^{-1}$.

How can I work with this to prove what the jordan form associated to $J^T$ is?

EDIT** I HAVE SOLVED THIS PROBLEM*** :D

Comment: The transpose of a Jordan normal form is equivalent to the original normal form. Try to see why this is true for small matrices, specifically take a Jordan basis and literally flip it over, and see what happens to the matrix of $A$ in that base.

Comment: I tried this, and found that $J^T = M J M$ where $M$ is an antidiagonal matrix consisting of all 1's. I'm not sure how to prove what the jordan form associated to $J^T$ is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old problem everyone encounters, and even showed up in some qualifying exams (for example in Berkeley and Princeton). The hint is to consider a single Jordan block and try to find a linear transformation to change it to its inverse. The linear transformation should be easy to write if you start out from $2\times 2$ case and see what the general situation might be like.

Alternatively, I think it should be clear from the Jordan block that its transpose must be similar to itself by using characteristic polynomial/minimal polynomial. Each Jordan block corresponds to $(x-\lambda)^{n}$, and you can show this for its transpose as well.